# Reference a method from a different Java file

Tags: java

I'm new to Java programming and am facing a (most likely) easy problem that I don't seem to be able to get across nor understand.

I have three different java files, one where I create an interface (SimulatorGui.java), other where I am creating a panel to use on the jTabbedPanel created in the interface (CollisionPanel.java - CollisionPanel class) and a third one, where I run a code that will create the output needed (Collision.java - Colision class).

In the Collision.java main method, I am doing the following:

```
  public static void main (String[] args) {

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Simulation start procedures">
    Tally statC = new Tally ("Statistics on collisions");
    Collision col = new Collision (100, 50);
    col.simulateRuns (100, new MRG32k3a(), statC);
    //</editor-fold>


    new SimulatorGUI().setVisible(true);
    CollisionPanel update = new CollisionPanel();
    update.updatepanel();
```

The first block, will create the desired output. I then want to send that output to the updatepanel! I am not passing any arguments to the method as I am still trying to debug this. updatepanel method is created in the file CollisionPanel as following:

```
public void updatepanel(){
    System.out.println ("debug");
    jTextArea1.setText("update\n");
}
```

What happens then is that when I run the Collision.java file it will output the "debug" text but won't set the text to the jTextArea1 (append doesn't work aswell). I then created a button to try and do so and in that case it works. In CollisionPanel.java:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    updatepanel();
}
```

This does the trick! I've searched and tried different things but can't seem to understand why this won't work.

Thanks in advance for your help, hope I've made the problem clear!

Comment: Rather post an http://sscce.org/ for help sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I've eventually got the problem, and it is because of the IDE, you see in your main method you initiate a new `CollisionPanel`, which is wrong, netbeans has already added and initiated that panel in the `SimulatorGUI`, so now what you need to do is add a get method in the `SimulatorGUI` to get the initiated panel, then call the update method on that panel.

So add this to `SimulatorGUI`:

```
public CollisionPanel getCollisionPanel1() {
    return collisionPanel1;
}
```

replace your old `updatePanel()` method with:

```
 void updatepanel(String str) {
            System.out.println ("debug");
            jTextArea1.setText(str);
         //   jTextArea1.revalidate();
            jLabel1.setText("test");
        }
```

after that change your main too look like this:

```
            SimulatorGUI simulatorGUI = new SimulatorGUI();
            simulatorGUI.setVisible(true);
            CollisionPanel cp=simulatorGUI.getCollisionPanel1();
            cp.updatepanel("Hi");
```

and dont forget to remove the old `updatePanel()` method call from your `CollisionPanel` constructor, because now you can simply call `cp.updatePanel("text here");` in your `SimulatorGUI` class instead of calling it only in the constructor.

I hope this is easy to grasp, if you're unsure let me know

Comment: As I am using Netbeans (forgot to mention) that code is automatically generated! As I stated on another comment, not sure if this is what it is intended with SSCCE but here are the links for the code of these files:

Collision.java - pastebin.com/BYs162Rv 
CollisionPanel.java - pastebin.com/UcwPUVhP 
SimulatorGUI.java - pastebin.com/9iXuhFzM

Comment: An SSCCE is a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example. What you did is good, but it's missing classes like RandomStream etc, a SSCCE is supposed to be the shortest possible code that describes/illustrates your problem, and can be run from a simple copy and past, which even after your pastebin examples as I said I was still missing references. I do not mean now for you to give me the referenced files, as I said create an example and once the example is corrected you can simply transfer it to your actual code, thus lessening even more confusion

Comment: Thank you for walking me through this. I believe this can now be considered an SSCCE as I removed all the unnecessary code for this example:

Collision.java - http://pastebin.com/0eNhcGcG

Comment: A quick question why not in your CollisionPanel constructor call upadatePanel()

Comment: Believe it or not, it fixed it! It works as I was trying to! :D
When I run Collision.java the gui is displayed and the values are set as wanted in the updatepanel()!

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes this was the quickiest way but I wasnt sure if thats what you wanted, glad its working, dont forget to mark this as answered using the tick under to the answers 'upvote'/'downvote'

Comment: It is what I wanted, for now! Before I close this question, I'll steal  just a little bit more time from you if that's okay. I just tried to do the same as before but now passing arguments when I call the method.

But I am now getting an error when I call the updatePanel() in the CollisionPanel constructor. I understand why, as I am not passing any arguments to the method but can't figure out how to fix it.

Here are both the updated files:
CollisionPanel.java - http://pastebin.com/NZfz5pBt
Collision.java - http://pastebin.com/1k55mhyH

Comment: Okay please wait I found the exact problem just explaining it etc

Comment: This did indeed fix the problem and I believe I understood it clearly! @David Kroukamp I seriously thank you for you time and walking me through the solution of my problem! 

I will now move on to the next phase! Thank you once again!

Comment: @Luis Afonso Teixeira Glad to help someone thats willing to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

Where do you add your CollisionPanel to the main GUI? I fear that this is your problem, and that you need to do this for your code to work. In fact where do any of your three classes get a reference to the others? For different classes to work in a program, there must be some communication between them. Understand that if you create a CollisionPanel object inside the GUI, and create another CollisionPanel object inside of the main method, calling a method on one object will have *no effect* on the other since they are two completely distinct entities.

For example, this code:

```
new SimulatorGUI().setVisible(true);
CollisionPanel update = new CollisionPanel();
update.updatepanel();
```

It appears that you are in fact calling updatePanel() on a CollisionPanel, but it's not on any CollisionPanel that is visualized in your GUI.

Consider giving SimulatorGUI a method that allows one to pass the CollisionPanel into it so that it can use it. This may in fact be a constructor parameter:

```
CollisionPanel update = new CollisionPanel();
SimulatorGUI simulatorGUI = new SimulatorGUI(update);
update.updatePanel();
```

Meaning SimulatorGUI's constructor would have to look something like:

```
public SimulatorGUI(CollisionPanel update) {
   this.update = update;
   // add update to GUI somewhere
}
```

Comment: +1 I do agree this could be the problem, it would help though if the OP makes an SSCCE

Comment: @DavidK: Agree, and agree with your EDT rec. 1+ back to ya.

Comment: I'm sorry, as I've just heard about SSCCE, i'm not sure if this is what it is supposed to be, but i've created these links at pastebin with the full code for the files mentioned. Here they are:

Collision.java - http://pastebin.com/BYs162Rv
CollisionPanel.java - http://pastebin.com/UcwPUVhP
SimulatorGUI.java - http://pastebin.com/9iXuhFzM

Comment: @LuisAfonsoTeixeira: you're doing wrong just what I thought you were doing wrong -- creating two CollisionPanel objects, one placed on the GUI, and one created in the main method. Don't do that. Create only one of these objects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I now understand what I was doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

There are three different levels when developping a `GUI`:

- The view: the graphical component
- The Model: the code that you run
- The controller: checks if are update on the model in order to refresh the view.

So When you first start your program, the view will have the value assigned in the code; for instance say you created your `JTextArea` with the initial value **type here**. The view will show the `JTextArea` with the text **type here**. 
When a change is made to the model, the view is not *aware* of it, it is job of the controller to check for update on the model and then refresh the view.

So this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    updatepanel();
}
```

Will generate an event that say a property has been modify. So the controller will update the view.

Other than that, the change will not appear on the view.

Hope this helps..

Comment: I see what I mean, that was indeed one thing I thought about, but am still trying to learn more about it!